# php strtotime function (2)

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I started to learn PHP and have to find a mistake (maybe in this code):

```
if($newvalues["year"] != null)
   $newvalues["year"] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($newvalues["year"]."-01-01"));
```

The new date has to be saved in the array "$newvalues", but when I press the save button, it doesn't save anything. Only if the textfield "year" is empty, the other items can be saved.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding debugging code to that, so you can see all the values that your code is working with, and that the right part of the `if` statement is being triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically doing:

```
100 * 80 / 80
```

Just save it as

```
if($newvalues["year"] != null)
   $newvalues["year"] .= "-01-01";
```

Or better yet, represent it as a `DateTime` object:

```
$newvalues = array("year" => 2012);
if ($newvalues["year"] != null) {
    $newvalues["year"] = new DateTime("{$newvalues["year"]}-01-01");
}
var_dump($newvalues["year"]);
```

Using a DateTime object (And the DateTime family) gives you much better and more flexible control over your date/times.